# Policy set for cross Bucket replication in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli, policy

I need to replicate my bucket objects to another region of the bucket, in that I enabled versioning and set source and destination bucket of the specified region, it also enabled and set in my source bucket cross replication.

My query is, I need to apply IAM policy to the destination bucket, but I don't want to do aws iam cli. Instead of that I have used

command:

```
        aws s3api put-bucket-policy
  --region myregion
  --bucket source_bucket_name
  --policy file://myfile.json
```

myfile.json

```
    {
         "Version": "2017-1-17",
         "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
          "Statement": [
             {
              "Sid":"Stmt123",
              "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal":{
                    "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::my role"
             },
           "Action":[
              "s3:ReplicateObject",
              "s3:ReplicateDelete"
            ],
              "Resource":"Destination.Bucket/*"
              }

            ]
           }
```

Error:

> stderr": "\nAn error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the
>   PutBucketPolicy operation: Policy has invalid resource.So how to apply
>   the json file for replication.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is your resource value an ARN? Does it start with "arn:aws:s3:::"? Look at the examples here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Right, iam passing like this only in the resource key arn:aws:s3:::Destinationbucket/*,  Still getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Whether I need to add any  policies to my job file, since it shows error as malformed policy.Can you guys help me in this.

Comment: weird if you have `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Destinationbucket/*"` and ` Destinationbucket` is the right name of your bucket it must work